# manually install npm packages?

Tags: selenium, npm, protractor

I'm experimenting with protractor and following [tuturial on github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md). NPM was already present on my system, I succesfully downloaded protractor and now I'm proceeding with

```
webdriver-manager update
```

Which fails with

```
downloading http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar...
Error: Got error Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar
Updating chromedriver
Error: Got error Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/chromedriver_win32.zip
downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/chromedriver_win32.zip...
```

Per earlier answered equal questions I double checked my npm proxy settings, all fine for http and https. Also I can see the username:password@proxy definition in .npmrc in my userprofile directory (c:/Users/my-name), the files are also present on the internet. Also the npm install action of protractor worked well. Now is it possible to manually (via browser download the relevant files and have them exploded and installed in the designated places?

I'm on windows 7 SP 1, 32 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can manually install the webdriver-manager file in "node_modules\protractor\bin".

By the way , the error message really looks like you have a trouble to access internet.
Did you try to set these variables before launching your npm command:

set HTTP_PROXY=http://'your http proxy ip':'your proxy port'

set HTTPS_PROXY=http://'your https proxy ip':'your proxy port'

Comment: dr jerry , you replied yourself below with the answer I gave.I do not think this is a good behavior.Do you ?

Comment: Sorry did not notice I think. Referenced your answer.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question:

As Yannick mentioned: I only set the proxy configuration with npm config ... For this you also need to set the environment variables

```
set PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@proxyserver
set HTTP_PROXY=%PROXY%
set HTTPS_PROXY=%PROXY%
```